# $x^2 + y^2 = 0 \,\,(mod \,p)$ is congruent to $(\frac {x} {y})^2 = - 1 \,\,(mod \,p)$ how?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I'm working through this problem:

"For what primes *p* do there exist integers *x* and *y* with gcd(*x*, *p*) = 1 and gcd(*y*, *p*) = 1, such that *x*<sup>2</sup> + *y*<sup>2</sup> ≡ 0 (mod *p*)?"

And I'm looking at the hint in the back of the book and it says:

"**HINT:** *y* has an inverse (mod *p*) --" [which I know, because they're coprime] "-- and *x*<sup>2</sup> + *y*<sup>2</sup> ≡ 0 (mod *p*) is equivalent to (*x*/*y*)<sup>2</sup> ≡ - 1 (mod *p*)."

---

My question is, how is *x*<sup>2</sup> + *y*<sup>2</sup> ≡ 0 (mod *p*) equivalent to (*x*/*y*)<sup>2</sup> ≡ - 1 (mod *p*)? Am I missing something really simple here, because I can't see how this is true.

Comment: Do a few random algebraic manipulations; you'll probably stumble on it. This doesn't really have anything to do with modular arithmetic; it would be the same if $x,y$ were rational variables, or real or complex variables rather than integers-mod-$p$ variables.

Comment: $$
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^2 + y^2 & = & 0 & \pmod{p} \\
x^2 & = & -y^2 & \pmod{p} \\
x^2\,y^{-2} & = & -1 & \pmod{p}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Comment: Ugh, I feel stupid now... thanks to the both of you for responding. Maybe it's time to call it quits for the night...

Answer (score 1):

All the equations below are made $\mod p$.

We have

$-1 \equiv (\frac{x}{y})^2 \equiv (\frac{x}{y}) \cdot (\frac{x}{y})  \equiv (x y^{-1}) \cdot (x y^{-1}) \equiv x^2 (y^{-1})^2$

Then, multiplying by $y$ in both sides,

$-y \equiv x^2 (y^{-1})^2 y \equiv x^2 y^{-1}$

and multiplying both sides by $y$  again

$-y^2 \equiv x^2$

So, adding $y^2$ in both sides

$0 \equiv x^2 + y^2$

Therefore,

$-1 \equiv (\frac{x}{y})^2 \Rightarrow 0 \equiv x^2 + y^2$

But, from this proof, it's very easy to see that

$0 \equiv x^2 + y^2 \Rightarrow -1 \equiv (\frac{x}{y})^2 $

(just do the steps in the reverse order).

Thus, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

So now the question is: for which $p$ prime do $x^2+y^2$ has not trivial solutions in $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

The answer comes from the hint: for which primes $p$ the polynomial $z^2+1$ has a solution? And the answer to this is pretty simple: when $4|p-1$, when $4$ divides $p-1$. Why is that? It all comes from the fact that the multiplicative subgroup of a finite field is cyclic. There exist one element $g\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $g^n$ generates all the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. In particular we get that $$g^{p-1}= 1\mod{p}.$$
Removing the case in which $p=2$, we get that $p-1$ is always even and will get that $$g^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=-1\mod p.$$
It is clear that the answer to the question now is asking for an $n$ such that $$g^{2n}=-1\mod p$$ $$g^{4n}=1=g^{p-1}\mod p$$ which has always two solutions, $1$ and $p-1$. But will have $4$ solutions only when $4|p-1$.

P.S. BTW in case $p=2$: $$x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2\mod 2.$$ So basically $(0,0),(1,1)$ are solutions. It is trivial because the polynomial splits but still requires some attention.

Comment: maybe it wasn't needed... Oh well... hope it doesn't get downvoted for nothing.